# display string in PHP as plain text only

Tags: php

I have data in a database that looks like the text in this pastebin example: http://pastebin.com/ipuXarEX

I have got this to display only plain text:

```
$TicketUpdateDisplay = preg_replace('/<[^<]+?>/','',$result2["displaydata"]);
```

which works fine, however it removes ALL the line breaks and displays this string at the top:

```
v\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} o\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} w\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
```

and then the rest of the data

the code in the database sometimes has a few line breaks between lines/paragraphs and i want to reduce this. Not remove the line breaks totally, but just display maybe 1

Update

I have also tried:

'$TicketUpdateDisplay = strip_tags(stripslashes(nl2br($result2["displaydata"])));'

Comment: It depends.  Are you trying to display it on a page or export it to a file?

Comment: Okay, I think I know what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah? Ok, what do you think ?

Comment: You shouldn't parse html using regexp

Comment: You could use the php `strip_tags` function instead of the regex. Documented here: [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: Check the first paste bin example. That's what's in that variable

Comment: @user3223205 Please mark an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `echo nl2br(strip_tags($string));`

Adding a `trim()` to this works even better.

Try this: `nl2br(trim(strip_tags($string)))`

Comment: Check my update - this is something else I also tried

Comment: What's not to understand. It's just something else I have tried which is something you suggested. So in saying it's not going to work

Comment: Okay, I see. You haven't actually done as I suggested there, as you have changed the order that the functions run (the order of execution is very important here).

Answer (score 0):

Try this since HTML ignores PHP line breaks (`\n`):

```
$string = str_replace("\n",'<br>',$string);
```

Assuming that `$string` contains the data.

Also, *as suggested in the comments*, you could use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br%28%29):

```
$string = nl2br($string);
```

Comment: why not use nl2br() instead?

Comment: just tried that - check here http://pastebin.com/ycKbHnHK - thats what it outputs. also check the pastebin example in my original question for what it looks like in the database

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should do that unless you have multiple line breaks in your code.  Does the `nl2br` work?

Comment: Check my update too, it's the other option I have tried

Comment: I tried using nl2br($result2["displaydata"]) and that's still got the line large breaks

Comment: Are there multiple `<br>`s inserted or just one per line?

Comment: There are no <br> tags. Check my pastebin link, the data I'm displaying a full of CSS code etc

Comment: I meant in the source code of the page in order to separate the lines.

Comment: I don't know.  There is no reason why it should not be working.  It works perfectly fine when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is get rid of the additional backslashes:

```
if (magic_quotes_gpc())) {
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}
```

*Magic quotes have been removed in 5.4*

Then, strip all the tags and trim the resulting string:

```
$value = trim(strip_tags($value));
```

And finally, get rid of extraneous newlines:

```
$value = preg_replace('/\n\s+$/m', '', $value);
```

Comment: this is still displaying the same :(

Comment: @user3223205 I've tested this on the given HTML; you could try making the `stripslashes()` unconditional, but that's all I can think of.

Comment: Hi, what was the HTML you used?

Comment: am i missing anything from the magic_quotes_gpc part? I copied your code exactly